# How can I prove the following logic statement deductively?

Tags: logic, conditional-statements, proof

I have the following logic statement:

```
If (P OR Q) and
   (P => Q) and
   (Q => P)
Then 
   (P AND Q)
```

I'm told to use Dorothy's Law, which is:

```
If (A => B)
Then (A OR B => B)
```

I can't figure out the exact rules of inference and/or laws needed to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Your use of commas is ambiguous here.  Please use parenthesis instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
P => Q Therefore P OR Q => Q
Q => P Therefore Q OR P => P

Finally,

(P OR Q) AND (Q OR P)=( P AND (Q OR P)) OR (Q AND (Q OR P))
                     =((P AND Q) OR (P AND P))  OR ((Q AND Q) OR (Q AND P))
                     =(P AND Q) OR (Q AND P)
                     =P AND Q
```

Comment: Don't you have to start with (P OR Q) AND (P => Q) AND (Q => P)?

Comment: @amorimluc You can refer to this [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183974/find-an-equivalent-to-p-lor-q-land-p-to-r-land-q-to-s?rq=1]link

Comment: Sorry, one more question then I'll accept. I'm still unsure why you start with (P OR Q) AND (Q OR P). Are you starting backwards from the conclusion? Would you mind adding a few more intermediate steps to the solution?

Comment: @amorimluc I have not started directly. Notice first two lines, I have ANDed them...